# Find value from JSON using key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON file in below format. I want to get value i.e. (mouse, aets, infor) 
using key values.

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "item_alias_list": "mouse",
      "eancode": "19",

    },
    {
      "item_alias_list": "aets",
      "eancode": "11",

    },
    {
      "item_alias_list": "infor",
      "eancode": "23",

    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

suppose

```
var Data =

 {"list":[{"item_alias_list":"mouse","eancode":"19"},
      {"item_alias_list":"aets","eancode":"11"},
      {"item_alias_list":"infor","eancode":"23"}]
 };

var len = Data.list.length;
for(var i = 0; i<len; i++)
{
     for(var key in Data.list[i])
     {
           alert(key +"="+ Data.list[i][key])
     }
}
```

**live Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/PQcFx/40/

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = {"list":[ 
{

"item_alias_list":"mouse",
"eancode":"19",
}
,   {

"item_alias_list":"aets",
"eancode":"11",
}
,   {

"item_alias_list":"infor",
"eancode":"23",
}
]};

// get "mouse"
var ret = a.list[0].item_alias_list;
```

Comment: Thanks xdazz in some cases item_alias_list is dynamic so i dont know the key?????

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma after the number strings for valid JSON

Comment: comma does not affect any thing

Comment: maybe not for this operation... but can cause problems in cases where you need a VALID JSON object